# Discord.py How can I give everyone money in my json file/database trough a command?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Question in the title!
I use the code from swastik on yt!
i thought maybe something like that:

```
everyone = ---
everyone[str(everyone.id)]["wallet"] += 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("nameofjson","r") as f:
   everyone = json.load(f)
for i in everyone:
   everyone[str(i)]["wallet"] += 100
```